# Fusion drive unavailable after HD erase

Tags: macos, core-storage

I wanted to erase the 3 TB Fusion HD on my iMac in order to install a clean system and start from scratch. The erase went fine except right at the end when it said something about core storage... (which I failed to capture, sorry)... and now the machine behaves as though the drive only sort of half exists.

- There is no 'sub-disk' when I look with Disk Utility - i.e., there is no indented drive listed below "Macintosh HD"
- The "Erase" tab is absent in Disk Utility
- All partition options are greyed out in Disk Utility
- I can boot in Recovery Mode, but I can't reinstall OS X because there is no drive available - it asks me to select a disk, but no disks are listed
- diskutil sees the drive fine (screenshots below)

In case it's not clear from the images, distil cs list shows:

```
Logical Volume Group C970ADA-0D05-42AA-9E9C-403ED0E5335
Name: Macintosh HD
Status: Online
(3.1Tb)

    Physical Volume 7DAE3935-D0AD-42AE-AE2A-F6001F09187
    Index: 0
    Disk: disk0s2
    (120Gb)

    Physical Volume BA37C009-F93C-4EAF-9EF3-9C19772BD91C
    Index: 1
    Disk: disk1s2
    (3Tb)
```

[image: diskutil cs list screenshot]

diskutil list shows:

[image: diskutil list screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You probably deleted your Logical Volume and the superior  Logical Volume Family.

To create a new one boot to Recovery Mode, open Terminal and simply enter:

```
diskutil cs list #to get the lvgUUID (UUID of the Logical Volume Group)
diskutil cs createVolume lvgUUID type name size
```

or in your case:

```
diskutil cs createVolume C970ADA-0D05-42AA-9E9C-403ED0E5335 jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%
```

Comment: Hi There. Massively appreciate the advice.

Comment: Will let you know if it works.

Comment: I get an answer saying "the ice (100) must be followed by a letter suffix"... Maybe there was one but it got cut off? I can only see half of that last zero in your post...

Comment: Just found the percent sign on the end! Let's see if it works now...

Comment: SUCCESS! You are completely awesome. Many, many thanks. All the best,

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward You're welcome ;-)